# Cannot view dates of emails(no date field), in my CSV file exported from MS Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am using Outlook 2010 - I have my emails showing in there.

and exported my emails, into a csv file.
(file..options..advanced...export..export to a file..

I have opened that csv file in excel

Here is a list of the fields it shows. I see "Date" doesn't appear among them.

```
Subject Body    From: (Name)    From: (Address) From: (Type)    To: (Name)  To: (Address)   To: (Type)  CC: (Name)  CC: (Address)   CC: (Type)  BCC: (Name) BCC: (Address)  BCC: (Type) Billing Information Categories  Importance  Mileage Sensitivity
```

Any idea why "Date" isn't included, and how to include it?

Also, (and less importantly, and as a very secondary issue) is there a convenient way to read the csv file? reading an email with a long body, in excel, is not convenient, I need to select all of the body from the cell and copy/paste it into notepad.

Answer (score 2):

Date is not an exportable field in Outlook (for CSV files).  It's odd (to me anyway), but it's been like that for a long time.

If you happen to also have Access installed, you can use it to import mail from Outlook, and then you could dump the table into Excel.

In Access check out the "External Data" tab and click "More" to look for "Outlook Folder".

- [Import form Outlook Video tutorial (YouTube)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3uhYu-2J7k8)
- [Access 2010: Export Database Table To Excel 2010 (AddictiveTips.com)](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/access-2010-export-database-table-to-excel-2010/)

As for viewing the CSV.  Excel is a good way as it properly separates the fields (into cells), but otherwise a CSV is just plain text, so load it into Notepad or Wordpad (or another text editor like Notepad++).

Comment: thanks, i'll try that, i'm generating a pst file at the moment from outlook(started before you posted your answer), it's taking a long while and seems to be much bigger. like the csv was about 76MB and this is 1.5GB so far.  I'll give ms access a try once the pst is done.  The ultimate destination i'm going to then try, is to gmail. I had tried directly, yahoo mail to gmail via pop(an old yahoo account that supports pop), but gmail only took or copied a month's worth of email like 600 emails or so. Outlook managed to copy the lot from yahoo via pop.

Comment: your sentence saying "Date is not an exportable field in Outlook"  Is not really a true statement, it's only true of CSV. I have tried it with "pst" and read it in outlook, and it has the dates.

Comment: @barlop Since the .pst file can only be opened by Outlook, the date is not any more accessible in a .pst format. Also, I think your comment would be better off as an answer so that people could ask questions / contribute to it.

Comment: @geneorama  answers have to be answers.  also, I can't make sense of your comment. saying "Since the .pst file can only be opened by Outlook, the date is not any more accessible in a .pst format." <--- I never said that the date is more accessible within the pst file than within outlook (whatever that might mean). And anyhow, it's not just outlook that can open pst files. Program to recover outlook mail can too