# Export IMAP Email Folder into single CSV File with Dates

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, csv, export

I've been trying to export an Email folder into a CSV/JSON with the default Email columns, text content and date.
At first this seemed quite easy but when I used the Outlook export feature but it did not include a date. I then tried Thunderbird with the ImportExportTools Extension but it either exports all emails into separate files or you get an overview but without the actual email content. I've seen [this](https://superuser.com/questions/595999/cannot-view-dates-of-emailsno-date-field-in-my-csv-file-exported-from-ms-outl) but I currently can not use Access.

I really would appreciate some help. I'm so desperate that I've been considering writing a small Node.JS application to handle this question, but it seems way to overkill

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, only the items in the following pictures will be included in the exported CSV file, which is visible in the step of exporting to CSV.  These items do not contain Date, so the exported CSV file does not contain dates. I think it's by design.
[image]

What do you want to export these messages for? If it is used for backup, it can be exported to PST file, which can save the message more completely. If you need, please refer to: [Export or backup email, contacts, and calendar to an Outlook .pst file](http://As%20far%20as%20I%20know,%20only%20the%20items%20in%20the%20following%20pictures%20will%20be%20included%20in%20the%20exported%20CSV%20file,%20which%20is%20visible%20in%20the%20step%20of%20exporting%20to%20CSV.%20%20These%20items%20do%20not%20contain%20Date,%20so%20the%20exported%20CSV%20file%20does%20not%20contain%20dates.%20I%20think%20it%27s%20by%20design.%20%20%20What%20do%20you%20want%20to%20export%20these%20messages%20for?%20If%20it%20is%20used%20for%20backup,%20it%20can%20be%20exported%20to%20PST%20file,%20which%20can%20save%20the%20message%20more%20completely.%20If%20you%20need,%20please%20refer%20to:%20Export%20or%20backup%20email,%20contacts,%20and%20calendar%20to%20an%20Outlook%20.pst%20file.).

Comment: I am aware of this window and that's exactly why I asked my question. I wanted to know if there was a way outside of the possibilities of Outlook, .

I want to export and process these emails through a script in order to pipe them into a separate database. It is not for backup.